# How to Expand this unallocated space?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-server-2008, disk-management

From what I understand you can only have 4 partitions on a single disk. That's fine but how would I add the unallocated space to one of the other drives?

I have heard you can use 3rd party tools but I would really prefer to do this natively using Windows tools. Is it possible?

When I right click the unallocated space everything is greyed out:

[image]

Comment: You can't it's an extended partition.  You would have to delete it then create it again.  You should switch to GPT allows you more then 4 partitions

Comment: Can I switch to GPT if I am already using MBR without starting from scratch?

Comment: @throwayusername If you care about your data and don't have a backup you are confident you could restore from, you have bigger problems than unallocated space.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz fair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows partitioning tools (currently?) don't support resizing extended partitions (identified by the green box around your logical partition "H:").

To extend an extended partition (without destroying data in the logical partitions within it) you'll need to use a 3rd party partitioning utility, like (for example) a [GPartEd Live CD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).